# Renaming and Suggestions very slow in Codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

I am troubleshooting the above but can't find any hint.

I have a clean VS2022 without extensions and with almost all standard settings i believe.
I have one solution with two project, not very complex, the first is much larger.

In the first one everything works instantly.

In the second, when i want to rename a variable in a completely new empty namespace>class>ctor it takes around 10 seconds. (i don't see how a lone class in an empty namespace is connected to anything? )

(even says computing 1 reference in one file and that still takes up to almost 20 seconds)
[image]

(<kbd>F2</kbd> to open the rename window, takes some seconds time saying "finding token to rename"

Same for <kbd>Ctrl+.</kbd> Loading suggestions (10 sec), and enter applying suggestions (like adding a using namespace) => 10 sec

Finding all references <kbd>Shift+F12</kbd> works instantly anywhere.

Also going to definition (<kbd>F12</kbd>) for any class takes long.

In Xaml designer <kbd>Ctrl+.</kbd> ads namespaces instantly. Adding a new `event="button_click"` to codebehind takes also 10 sec.

(pc around high end a year ago)

Any tips?

Thanks!

Should be fast as in other projects..
Tested all kinds of commands to narrow down.
Disabled experimental / preview options.
Commented out some more complex parts of project.

EDIT:

I figured out the root of the slowdown.
I am using Reactive UI.
In ctors of Views i use             this.WhenActivated(d =>{}  ; the standard rui way.
in whenactivate I have several event implementations                lblTagsCheck.Events().PreviewMouseDown.Do((a) => ; still rui standard according to documentation, but the Events() part is what is causing it. When I replace it in the whole project with anything, my ide refactoring works instantly.  It's not the body content of the events, nor anything else. The more events i have in my ctors on any view, the slower everything I mentioned takes.

Kind of still have this question, maybe someone can answer it, how is that possible, if I have a class without any references to anything else, how is that effected by the Events() in ctors of classes in the project? Anyway going to investigate more into it.

How I went about troubleshooting: Simply ignored all errors throughtout the whole process; Excluded all files from the project except for lone testing class, tested renaming (20 sec with all included, 0 sec with all excluded); tried including one by one, until i figured out it was views, commeted out ctor, comented out parts of ctor, until I found the exact syntax causing it, revereted project back to original, commented out syntax, no problems (except for errors)

Troubleshooting Events() now.

Comment: Which exact build do you use? 17.8.4 fixes a [bug regarding the display of debug values on mouseover](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-Release-178-Hovering/10518414). Maybe your problem ist not in the renaming code, but the actual visualization of the result takes so long because the issue is related to the aforementioned one.

Comment: Yes, I am on 17.8.4, have this problem since the last at least 3 updates

Comment: Is the same solution don't have any problem in the old version VS?

Comment: I am going to try VS2019 and 22 on a virtual machine, but still not sure what I would look for it behaves differently.

Comment: I cannot remember if it ever worked for this solution.
I have now tested on a fresh Windows 11 VM with VS2022, but no luck, the same happens there.

Comment: I have updated my question with solutions i have so far. Reactive UI Events() are causing the slowdown even in seperate class. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: ReactiveMarbles.ObservableEvents.SourceGenerator, is being updated
https://github.com/reactivemarbles/ObservableEvents/issues/204